# How to add new column to stream in Pentaho DI, without blocking the stream, new column value is not constant

Tags: pentaho, kettle

[image]

I have such pipeline result from main stream in `sv` node as below
[image]

and result of node secondary node which in the top of the picture
[image]

and at the result I should get such result
[image]

how to get result like result of cartesian but non blocking the stream

criteria:

1. it should not block streaming
2. but it should produce a cartesian join type result
3. implement via ? the sign in the table_input itself will not work either, since in a real case it already works with the delta

How to add new column without blocking the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `table_cnt` is dynamic and will change record, you could set it as a variable. You transformation will look something as below

`Table Input --> Set Variable (total_cnt as variable set at ROOT level or Job Level)`

[image]

Next, the main transformation can use the `Get Variable` step to get the rows that was set previous. A sample workflow will look as below.

`Table Input --> Get Variable --> ... rest of the flow`

[image]

This approach doesn't use `JOIN ROW` step and also doesn't block the stream. It appends rows the existing main table input flow. To know more about using variables in Pentaho, you can refer to the [Pentaho wiki](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.4/Products/Variables).

Answer (score 0):

Rishus sollution will work. A much easier sollution is not using cartesian product, but just add to both flows a column (1::int as key) and then connect with stream lookup on that key, and then in SV2 dump the key...